# Why is the comma optional in C++ variadic function declarations?

Tags: c++, syntax

Is there a difference in these two declarations?

```
int foo( int a, ... );
```

and

```
int foo( int a ... );
```

If there is no difference, what was the point of making the second syntactically valid?

Comment: Avoid **varadic** functions like the plague in C++. It undermines the ethos of strong typing. There is a multitude of reasons not to do it and also a multitude a ways around any problem that you think requires it.

Comment: I do avoid them, and I agree with the advice.  I use them so little that I never noticed this syntactic oddity.  It seems very strange.

Comment: Wow, it really compiles even without a comma.

Comment: @EdHeal You are off-topic. You should at least try to answer the actual question, instead of simply telling him 'don't do that'.

Comment: @PaulManta: Well, that's why it was left as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: @Ed S - Thanks - That is why it was a comment. My comment still holds and I (for one) have never needed the requirement in C++ to use varadic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is speculation, but in C++ in can make sense to have a function with no other parameters, e.g. `void f(...)` whereas in C a function like this has no use (that I know of) so `...` must follow some other parameter and hence, a comma.

From a grammar point of view, it's simpler to simply allow `void f( int a ... )` and give it the obvious meaning than it is to disallow it and it's not going to cause much of a burden on compiler writers or any confusion for programmers.

(I originally thought it might be something to do with making the grammar for parameter packs more regular but I discovered that it was explicitly allowed in C++03 in any case.)

Comment: How can void f(...) be used?  There's no way to invoke va_start without an argument name!

Comment: @WilliamPursell: It can be "used" for a fallback for overload resolution in, e.g. SFINAE situations.

Comment: In C (atleast prior to C99) `void f();` was actually equal to `void (f...);` That is an empty argument list in the function defintion means the function can take "any" number of arguments, while an empty argument list in the function declaration means the function takes no arguments.

Comment: @CharlesBailey you are right, I meant an empty argument list in the function declaration means the number of arguments is unknown, while an empty argument list in the function definition means that the function takes no arguments.

Comment: @TommyA: Old-style function declarations and definitions are still legal (but "obsolescent") in C99 *and* C11. But `void f();` isn't equivalent to `void f(...);`. The former specifies a *fixed* but unknown number and type(s) of arguments; the latter (if it were legal without at least one explicit parameter) would permit different calls to pass different numbers and types of arguments.