# Weird compilation output

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I've just compiled this code:

```
void foo(int bar...) {}

int main()
{
   foo(0, 1);
   return 0;
}
```

And the compilation output was really weird:

> g++ test.c

Output:

> Nothing

and

> gcc test.c

Output:

> test.c:1:17: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '...' token

I know that there is no comma after parameter, this question about strange compilation output.

I understand why this is invalid in C, but cannot understand why it is valid in C++.

Comment: For what? gcc means line 1, not 17

Comment: @Levon thats line 1, and **column** 17.

Comment: What's weird about this? The code compiles as C++ and is invalid C. What were you expecting?

Comment: I can't understand why it's valid in C++

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov because C++ is not C.

Comment: @H2CO3: That doesn't really answer the question. C requires a comma before the `...`; in C++, the comma is optional. That strikes me both as a gratuitous inconsistency between C and C++, and as a silly glitch in the C++ grammar itself. I can think of no benefit in making the comma optional. It's perfectly reasonable to ask why the C++ grammar is written that way (without disputing the fact that it is).

Comment: This question is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274570/why-is-the-comma-optional-in-c-variadic-function-declarations

Comment: @KeithThompson I think you misunderstood the question here. OP seemed to think this was some kind of error/bug in the compiler as he didn't know the comma was optional in C++. However until I managed to explain this to him, he still thought that C and C++ treated variadic functions the same way - this last comment of mine wanted to reflect to the fact that they don't. Of course, one can ask why this inconsistency is there, but that wasn't in the scope of the question.

Comment: @H2CO3: And the actual reason, as David Heffernan cited by linking to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274570, is that C++, unlike C, permits a variadic function with no fixed parameters. In C, it makes sense to require the comma because it always follows a fixed argument declaration. In C++, `void f(...);` is legal, and a comma before the `...` wouldn't make sense. IMHO it would have been cleaner to require the comma if (and only if) the `...` follows one or more fixed parameter declarations, but at least there's an explanation.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks! Yes, that's logical enough - I think the reason for why it is required as is is that the current approach is more consistent.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I'd say this question is really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274570/why-is-the-comma-optional-in-c-variadic-function-declarations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The other answer is correct (I upvoted), but just to give a reference [8.3.5 Functions clause 3]:

> parameter-declaration-clause:
>
> parameter-declaration-list<sup><sub>opt</sub></sup>...<sup><sub>opt</sub></sup>
>
> parameter-declaration-list , ...

This means that the comma is *optional* in C++, but not in C. You can also write `void foo(...)` in C++, because the parameter declaration list is also optional.

As for the reason why, in C++ templates, `test(...)` is common when using SFINAE for a "catch-all" function. However, in C, there is no usage for `foo(...)` and hence it is illegal.

Comment: If you could use `void foo(...)` in C, what would you use as the second parameter to `va_start`?

Comment: @AlanCurry: `void foo(...)` is illegal in C.

Comment: +1 [8.3.5/4] *[...]Where syntactically correct and where “...” is not part of an abstract-declarator, “, ...” is synonymous with “...”.*

Answer (score 7):

The thing is C++ allows the

```
returntype funcname(optional_param...)
```

syntax for variadic functions, while C does not.

Comment: Same question - But there are no templates in this function. Should it still work anyway?

Comment: @Nikita what templates? I haven't ever mentioned templates in my answer. This is valid C++ and invalid in C.

Comment: So you mean that variadic functions in C++ doesn't require comma after last named parameter in the list, while C does?

Comment: There is no variadic function outside of variadic templates. I don't think that syntax is allowed in C++, can you provide a reference?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas variadic functions are part of C and C++ since the stone age. What do you think `printf` is doing?

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:1999
6.7.5.1
parameter-type-list:
parameter-list
parameter-list , ...

ISO/IEC 14882:2011
8.3.5.3
parameter-declaration-clause:
parameter-declaration-listopt ...opt
parameter-declaration-list , ...

@H2CO3 Idk, it's not me

Comment: nice answer, didn't know that other difference between the two languages, argh.

Comment: void foo(int bar...);

So it's totally equivalent to

void foo(int bar, ...);

Yes?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov yes, that's what I'm saying. :) (Seems somebody enjoys downvoting me...)

Comment: @H2CO3 So weird. For what can i ever need this syntax?

Comment: @NikitaTrophimov for horrifying Linus Torvalds' eyes :)

Comment: It would appear the @DavidRodríguez-dribeas is incorrect here, but I can't locate a standards ref to back me up (Ah, Jesse has done the trick, and indeed Nikita had already got that ref)

Comment: @JensGustedt: Right... I always called those varargs functions... the standard does not provide a name for those. Let me rephrase it: the term `variadic` in the standard is applied only to variadic templates. Also, the C++ standard, in the compatibility annex (C) does not list this as a difference, that is why I asked for a quote validating the assertion that this is valid C++

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, ah so ok this was a question about the vocabulary. In the C standard these are called "variable arguments" as well as for functions as for macros. This term is not much in use because of the overloading of the noun "variable", I think.

Comment: @JensGustedt No, they aren't. Variables are value-holding entities residing in RAM. These kind of arguments are called **variadic**.

Comment: @H2CO3 they are commonly referred to as variadic, right. The discussion was about the wording that the standard applies for them, it is "variable arguments", trust me, I just looked it up.

Answer (score 4):

You simply stumbled upon on of the obscure differences between C and C++ language grammars. Yes, C++ allows your syntax, while C doesn't. In C++ the comma before `...` is optional, while in C it is always required. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

No comma version is allowed in C++ to allow for f(...) Why?

Consider
    void f() {}
In C this means "I accept anything" and in C++ this means "I accept nothing". ( void f(void) is "I accept nothing" in C)

In order to declare C "I accept anything" function in C++, you have to write
    extern "C" void f(...);