# How does this variable argument notation work?

Tags: c++, arguments, variadic-functions

In C++ I can define a function with a variable number of arguments like this:

```
void a(int a...) {
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
a(100, 200, 300);
```

However, apparently I can only access the first argument: The output of the call is `100`.

How do I access the other arguments with this notation?

Comment: [man `va_list`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg) for a starting point. But if you want to do something like this in C++11, forget the above and look up `variadic templates` instead.

Comment: Are you familiar with `va_list` or variadic functions in C or C++? You might want to search for `va_list`.

Comment: I didn't even know you could specify a type with C variadics. Can't see any evidence in C99 that this is supported, yet GCC 4.8 compiles it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Only the initial non-variadic arguments (of which there must be at least one) have their types specified. The others are accesses with the `va_arg` macro, which leaves any type checking up to the programmer.

Comment: @KeithThompson, Both are equivalent. It gives rise to the possibility of `Args args......` syntax :)

Comment: Prefer variadic templates. They are type-safe and come with less surprises.

Comment: Ah, now there's what I was wondering. [Why is `int a...` allowed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274570/why-is-the-comma-optional-in-c-variadic-function-declarations)

Comment: @Adam, Check Jerry's link. You don't need (and can't have) a controlled argument count.

Comment: @chris: Ah, you're right. C requires `(int a, ...)`, but c++ permits both that and `(int a ...)`. I'll delete my earlier incorrect comment. (And I even commented on [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274570/why-is-the-comma-optional-in-c-variadic-function-declarations).

Comment: @KeithThompson, (And I even read your comment without realizing it was you.)

Comment: @chris: What's scary is when I read a comment and find myself agreeing with it ("hey, this guy knows what he's talking about!"), and only then notice my own name at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code using your function `a`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>

void a(int a...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, a);
    int b = va_arg(args, int);
    int c = va_arg(args, int);

    std::cout << a << ", " << b << ", " << c << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    a(100, 200, 300);
    return 0;
}
```

The variable argument syntax does not know the number or type of the parameters. Therefore something in the parameter list must indicate the number and possibly the type of the parameters. There are several methods that are typically used to determine the number of parameters:

1. The first parameter is the number of parameters.
2. The last parameter is a delimiter, a NULL or other unique value, for example.
3. The first parameter has other embedded information that determines the number, order and type of the parameters, for example the format parameter for printf.

In this example, I've simply assumed there are three parameters. Calling `a` with more or less parameters will cause undefined behavior (read, random results, to a crash).

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax is ... unfortunate, and refers to a C-style vararg function.

In C++11 you should prefer variardic `template`s.  The easiest approach is something like this:

First, some helper code:

```
#include <utility>
template<typename Lambda>
void for_each_arg( Lambda&& unused ) {}

template<typename Lambda, typename Arg1, typename... Args>
void for_each_arg( Lambda&& closure, Arg1&& arg1, Args&&... args ) {
  closure( std::forward<Arg1>(arg1) );
  for_each_arg( std::forward<Lambda>(closure), std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

now, we use it:

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename... Args>
void foo( Args&&... args ) {
  for_each_arg( [](int x){
    std::cout << x << "\n";
  }, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
int main() {
  foo( 1, 2, 3 );
}
```

and we can access each argument, and ensure that they convert to `int`.  Note that the conversion to `int` is deferred until call of the body of `for_each_arg`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a var args interface you need to be able to tell from the named parameters how many arguments where provided in total. For example, the `<stdio.h>` function do that by having the format string be the last named argument followed by as many arguments as specified in the argument list. To access the arguments you need to use the various `va_...` functions and types.

You are much better off using variadic templates:

```
template <typename... T>
void f(T... a) {
    // just expand the parameter pack over here
}
```

Comment: this answer will be very useful if you were to elaborate on *how* you "expand the parameter pack"

Comment: @Bathsheba: in the simplest case you'd use `g(a...)` but that alone doesn't really help much and describing how to fullly to do it is rather involved! Probably the easiest approach is to use `auto t(std::tie(a...));` and then access `t` using `std::get<...>(t)`.

Comment: Yes I think you're right, and to go into any more detail is possibly outside the answer scope. So +1.

Answer (score 0):

Another variadic solution:

```
template<typename T, typename... Vs>
void print(T&& t, Vs&&... vs) {
  std::cout << std::forward<T>(t) << std::endl;
  int sink[] { (std::cout << " " << std::forward<Vs>(vs) << std::endl, 0)... };
  (void)sink; // silence "unused variable" warning                                        
}
```

Which has the benefit of not requiring helpers. We use pack expansion to forward each argument one at a time to cout. For syntax reasons, I leverage the comma operator so that the expression (cout..stuff.., 0) resolves to an integer, which we then discard into an array; this lets us use the pack expansion operator around our complex statement.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which enforces the type `int`.
But with a usage a little different

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

// Or you may use std::vector
void print(const std::initializer_list<int>& a) {
    for (auto elem : a) {
        std::cout << elem << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    print({1, 2, 3}); // extra braces.
    return 0;
}
```